# StackExchange.Redis deserialize hast to poco

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I'm using StackExchange.Redis as my redis client and it works nicely.  I store a number of values in a hash and currently do a manual mapping once I've got the the hash values out of the database

```
var values = database.HashGetAll(myKey);
```

Does anyone have a nice way deserializing/mapping an array of `HashEntry[]` into a poco?

Comment: an example using FastMember: https://gist.github.com/ajai8085/364d076e7070c1677d1075467ae720e2
warning: opinionated deserialize (which fits my opinion of when/how to use redis)

Comment: a later possible duplicate Q with better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814496/efficient-way-of-mapping-data-from-redis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None such is built in - I'm kinda of the opinion that libraries should be targeted - however, it would be pretty easy to hook something over the top using reflection or meta - programming perhaps with a tool like fastmember.

I'm not completely opposed to adding something inbuilt, though :)

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll have a look at fast member to get some inspiration then maybe submit a pull request. I guess this could also be published separately as a kind of extender